# Authentication for WSDL services

Tags: java, soap, wsdl

I have a SOAP webservice with

```
@WebService(serviceName = "VenueList")
```

and a method on that service to get the list

`@WebMethod(operationName = "getvenuelist")`

If any one make a POST request to this service: "http://192.168.29.20/SIP/VenueList?tester"
it will return the data.Iam using Glassfish 3.1 as the server, and Java.

1. What is the best way to provide authentication for SOAP services(current case)?
2. Why SOAP is said to be more secure than REST?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `WS-Security` specification for this purpose. Most libraries and frameworks support it (but implementations is usually vendor dependent in minor particular details).

Comment: Is there any good example of WS-Security usage. Since I have no idea about implementing WS-Security into the current SOAP service I have created.

Comment: I think that it will be better to search documentation for you particular app server that discribes how to implement secure web service using ws-security. Web Logic server has some examples, for example. I don't have any experience with Glassfish currently.

Answer (score 0):

Setting headers(username & password) into the service, and evaluating these header values from the server will make things work.

Here is the link

http://www.java.net/external?url=http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/application-authentication-with-jax-ws/